# How to change paint color/stroke after implementing UNDO function in canvas paint

Tags: android, android-canvas

In my Paint App I have implemented UNDO function and it's working fine. But if a change the paint brush color (or) paint brush stroke then all my previous drawn paths changing to the new paint color. The code is as follows:

```
public class CustomView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    public Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    public Paint mPaint, mBitmapPaint;
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    Canvas canvas;
    public ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    public ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

    private Bitmap im;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mPath = new Path();

        im = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int w = metrics.widthPixels;
        int h = metrics.heightPixels;
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        // mBitmapPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // mPath = new Path();
        // canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        undonePaths.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        paths.add(mPath);
        mPath = new Path();

    }

    public void onClickUndo() {
        if (paths.size() > 0) {
            undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        } else {

        }
        // toast the user
    }

    public void onClickRedo() {
        if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
            paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        } else {

        }
        // toast the user
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: after you undo, you should call invalidate() function with params that specificy the will-be-updated portion of screen, you now callign invalidate() without params which leads to whole screen update so the colors of previous touches also change.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I wanted to leave an answer for anyone that comes here. The solution is to keep track of separate `Paint` instances for each stroke (there should be exactly 1 Paint object per Path object).

Change your touch_up method to reset the mPaint, in addition to resetting the mPath.

```
private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    paths.add(mPath);
    mPath = new Path();
    mPaints.add(mPaint)
    // Creates a new Paint reference, but keeps the previous state (color, width, etc.)
    mPaint = new Paint(mPaint);
}
```

Then your onDraw method looks something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mPaths.size(); i++) {
    canvas.drawPath(mPaths.get(i), mPaints.get(i));
}
```